# Webkit animations

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations

Very new to CSS webkit animation, and very keen on learning it! And also plenty clueless!!!
So the couple of questions:

1. What is the best walkthrough/tutorial/official site for CSS webkits?
2. Do I need to install webkit before I can program it in my CSS files?

Thanks and regards!

Parijat

Comment: A brand new innovation, [Google](http://google.com) and well [webkit](http://webkit.org).

Comment: I wrote css3.bradshawenterprises.com, which is designed to cover the basics of animation in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/) is a rendering engine, used in Safari and Chrome. If you have either of those browsers you don't have to install anything. They have several articles about animation on their blog, but I'd also encourage you to [Google it](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=webkit+animation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) because there are lots of other useful articles out there too.

Comment: Googled it, but seems like everything is a little vague and ambiguous, with not one concrete source, thanks though!

Comment: I like my own tutorial/presentation :-) http://marakana.com/forums/html5/general/323.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to google for css3 animations.There are a **LOT** of tutorials. There is also one on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/default.asp). Read those to learn animations.

Webkit is a rendering engine and is used by chrome/safari. So instead of specific search for webkit, unless necessary, i would recommend you to go through searching for css3 tutorials.

For beginning, there are css3 animation generating websites, do look into those, they're helpful in visualizing dynamically what happens with changes in element values.

CSS3 animation generating websites : http://www.css3maker.com/css3-animation.html , http://css3generator.com/